# A flexbox property ignored on media query

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, position

I followed a YouTube video called "The 2020 HTML & CSS Crash Course - From Mockup to Product", everything is fine and works as it should, except in one thing (which I will explain), however the problem doesn't seem to happen on the teachers website, even though the code is exactly the same.

So, the problem is that in one of the media queries (650px), the .companies selector takes on display: flex, but it completely ignores the justify-content property and it breaks out of the container and off the screen, and this happens on my laptop, desktop, and I tried on my girlfriends macbook: same thing in all. It doesn't seem to happen in his, it works as it should as far as I can see. Anyway, I'll put the code below and also here's the link to the teachers codepen: https://codepen.io/designcourse/pen/bGdQGgQ 
Which I should mention, still has the problem on my computers, it's only on his videos where it doesn't happen (that I can see).

Thanks in advance, this is driving me mad.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="hero-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">WebDeveloper</a>

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <div class="hero-content">
        <h1>I help millions of people learn stuff</h1>
        <p class="subtitle">Teaching UI / UX &amp; Frontend Development</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="light-purple-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="stats">
        <li>
          <strong>26.5M</strong>
          <span>Youtube Views</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>535K</strong>
          <span>YouTube Subs</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>86</strong>
          <span>Courses</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>750</strong>
          <span>Video Tutorials</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>58</strong>
          <span>Countries</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="extended-wrapper carousel-container">
      <img src="images/arrow_copy_copy.svg" id="left-arrow" class="arrows" alt="">

      <ul class="carousel">
        <li>
          <blockquote>"Gary is a life saver. I don't have the time or money for a college education. My goal is to
            become a freelance web developer, and thanks to Gary, I'm really close."</blockquote>
          <cite>John Doe</cite>
        </li>
        <li>
          <blockquote>"Gary is a life saver. I don't have the time or money for a college education. My goal is to
            become a freelance web developer, and thanks to Gary, I'm really close."</blockquote>
          <cite>John Doe</cite>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <img src="images/arrow_copy_copy.svg" id="right-arrow" class="arrows right" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper move-up v-padding">
    <h2>Companies I've worked with.</h2>
    <ul class="companies">
      <li><img src="images/skillshare.svg" alt="skillshare" class="skillshare"></li>
      <li><img src="images/ps.svg" alt="plural sight" class="ps"></li>
      <li><img src="images/skillshare.svg" alt="skillshare" class="skillshare"></li>
      <li><img src="images/ps.svg" alt="plural sight" class="ps"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>


////// SCSS ///////


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,800&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #2B192F;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hero-wrapper {
  background: url('../images/bg_copy.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 1.5em;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .logo {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  ul {
    display: flex;

    li a {
      padding: 0 .6em;
    }
  }
}

.hero-content {
  margin: 4em 0 2em;

  .subtitle {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.light-purple-wrapper {
  background: #351F3A;
}

.stats {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(130px, 1fr));
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 2em;

  li {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  }

  strong {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }

  span {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: .7em;
  }
}

.arrows {
  display: none;;
}

.extended-wrapper {
  padding: 0 1.5em 2em;
  max-width: 1230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 1em;

  li {
    background: #422847;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}

blockquote {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

cite {
  color:#E379FF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-style: normal;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

cite::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 6px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #B728DC;
  top: -.3em;
}

.companies {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .4;

  li {
    margin: 2em 0;
  }

  .skillshare {
    width: 100px;
  }

  .ps {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .companies {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 650px) {
  body {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    padding: 1.5em 4em;
  }

  .carousel-container {
    display: flex;
  }

  .arrows {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: .5em; 
  }

  .right {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }

  ul.carousel {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    li {
      margin-right: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding: 2em;

      &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }

  .companies {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 853px) {
  body {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .stats {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .companies {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
  }

  .subtitle {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }

  h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  .v-padding {
    padding: 4em;
  }

  .light-purple-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 4em;
  }

  .move-up {
    margin-top: -7em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .stats li {
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(124, 89, 148);
    padding-right: 5%;

    &:last-child {
      border: none;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you mean the title moves outside of the container (slightly above it)? Cos that seems to be by design? when you say " it breaks out of the container and off the screen" - what does? the images or the title?

Comment: Here's your code in a pen... seems to look ok in Chrome. What browser are you using? https://codepen.io/mugwag/pen/bGVqJPd

Comment: Keep in mind that `justify-content: space-between;` will only take effect if there's space for it to put between elements. Works as expected for me in Chrome and FF Win 8.1. Probably share a picture of what's going wrong.

Comment: @Leon The problem only happens to the .companies section in the 650px media query, tried on chrome and firefox, the code in that codepen you linked worked fine for me also, but because the images aren't there.
Thanks


And to ZohirSalak, Yeah that makes sense, it's just I don't understand why I get the scrollbar but he didn't on his... I will try to put a photo to show what I mean. Thanks

Comment: @ZohirSalak Photo added

Comment: @JamesPointer thats exactly what it supposed to look like because there isn't enough space, try removing the padding from the parent Or lower the size of those images so there will be enough space for justify-content to be visible.

Comment: @ZohirSalak Removing the padding kind of worked, got them without the scrollbar at least, but still not much space between them and I can't change the size for some reason. But anyway your solution did what I needed so thanks a lot for that, really appreciate it.